# $x^y+y^x=19$ Find the value of $x-y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x^y+y^x=19$. Is that possible that we can find the value of $x-y$?

Can someone explain it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

$18^1 + 1^{18} = 19$. So the difference is $\pm17$.

Answer (score 3):

If $x$ and $y$ can be arbitrary real numbers, you cannot answer the question.

[image]

You can see there are infinitely many answers, with infinitely many possible values of $x-y$. In fact, $x-y$ can be any real number at all.

Other answers here explain well what happens when we know that $x$ and $y$ are integers--but the question as given does not say that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Suppose you're looking for nonnegative integers $x, y$. In that case, $x^y$ and $y^x$ are both perfect powers.